# What are the default lock screen settings on mac m1 air 2020

Tags: macos, lockscreen

[image]

What are the default lock screen settings on mac m1 air 2020 and what are the recommended ones.

Comment: The 'recommended' settings are whatever you find most useful for your work. Personally, 2 minutes would be too fast for me; and I suspect the default is more like 10 or 20 mins.

Comment: "Recommended" will be totally different depending on whether you live & work alone in a secure building, or whether you share a crowded workspace with others. One you don't need it to lock for an hour or so, the other as soon as you walk away from your desk.